# Verifying the memory usage using nbresuse - Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook

I have installed the Jupyter Extension nbresuse to verify memeory usage, but I struggle on how to display the memory limit (I can only see the memory usage)

https://github.com/yuvipanda/nbresuse/blob/master/README.md

The README advises three methods to display the memory limit:

(i) MEM_LIMIT environment variable. This is set by JupyterHub if using a spawner that supports it.

I installed Jupyter Hub, but what after?

(ii) In the commandline when starting jupyter notebook, as --ResourceUseDisplay.mem_limit.

I never start my Jupyter from the command line and I am not really sure how to do it adding "--ResourceUseDisplay.mem_limit"

(iii) In your jupyter notebook traitlets config file

I have no idea what is this and how to do it.

As anyone already done this and can guide me through the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for --ResourceUseDisplay.mem_limit.
you need to give the limit, in the below example the limit is 1024 bytes.

the example command in your terminal looks like this 
**$ jupyter notebook --ResourceUseDisplay.mem_limit=1024**